# for a long time

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

Jane: **He's been pressuring me to see them for a long time.** I have also been pressuring myself. It's just not that easy when you're not feeling well.

(He = Jane's ex-husband)

(Them = Jane's and her ex-husband's children)

Context: Jane has had and is having a depression so she hasn't seen her children a lot as she has been suffering.

Question: Can I use "for a long time" here even though Jane has seen her children a few times (but far from enough) since she got the depression?

Comment: "for a long time now" would be more accurate given your situation.

Comment: [since she got depressed: got=to become]

Comment: Yes, because "for a long time" refers to how long her ex has been pressuring her, not how long it's been since she's seen her kids.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to imply that the visits are not frequent enough than I would say something like:

> He's been pressuring me to see them more often for a long time.

This implies that she has seen the children, perhaps even recently, but overall it's not often enough.

Without adding that, it implies that a considerable (long) amount of time has past since the last visit.  More than that, it implies she hasn't seen them since the ex-husband first started pressuring her.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use something like "continuously" instead of "for a long time".

> He's been continuously pressuring me to see them.

Or better yet:

> He has repeatedly asked me to see them.